# Spock test framework: Difference between mock.getProperty('name') vs getName()

Tags: unit-testing, spock

What is the difference in a mocked instance between getProperty('name') vs getName()? I thought they meant the same thing but I keep having to swap between them because sometimes spock isn't happy with one or the other.

Let's say I have the following class

```
class Person {
    String name
}
```

And I'm testing some other class that is meant to update the person so I do something like this:

```
void "test something"() {
    Person personMock = Mock(Person)

    when:
    someObject.updatePersonName(personMock, 'new name')

    then:
    1 * personMock.getName() >> 'old name'
    1 * personMock.setName('new name')
}
```

The details of the simplified test aren't important. The point is that I'm verifying that a certain property is being read and updated. Sometimes when I run the tests I get complaints that personMock.getName() was never called and it helpfully shows that personMock.getProperty('name') was called instead. The test passes if I rewrite it to use that form. Until some time later it again complains that getProperty('name') wasn't called but getName() was.

I know that spock can't possibly be this flaky. I must have fumbled somewhere. So when should I use getName() and when getProperty('name')?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is strange that your code flip-flops, however if your are testing Groovy code then you should use `GroovyMock` instead of `Mock` (see also [docs](http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.1/all_in_one.html#GroovyMocks)), it has extra support for some of Groovys special features.

> When Should Groovy Mocks be Favored over Regular Mocks? Groovy mocks
>   should be used when the code under specification is written in Groovy
>   and some of the unique Groovy mock features are needed. When called
>   from Java code, Groovy mocks will behave like regular mocks. Note that
>   it isn’t necessary to use a Groovy mock merely because the code under
>   specification and/or mocked type is written in Groovy. Unless you have
>   a concrete reason to use a Groovy mock, prefer a regular mock.

In this case you (or your code) are using some of Groovys special features, i.e., the Groovy MOP method `getProperty`. `GroovyMock` uses the [GroovyMockInterceptor](https://github.com/spockframework/spock/blob/master/spock-core/src/main/java/org/spockframework/mock/runtime/GroovyMockInterceptor.java) which handles these special methods, e.g., normalizing `getProperty('x')` to `getX()`.

```
void "test something"() {
    Person personMock = GroovyMock(Person)

    when:
    someObject.updatePersonName(personMock, 'new name')

    then:
    1 * personMock.getName() >> 'old name'
    1 * personMock.setName('new name')
}
```

Comment: Yes I'm testing groovy code. Thanks for the tip about GroovyMock.

Comment: It's pretty had to tell because it's been an intermittent problem. The spock documentation has this to say about it: "Note that it isn’t necessary to use a Groovy mock merely because the code under specification and/or mocked type is written in Groovy. Unless you have a concrete reason to use a Groovy mock, prefer a regular mock". I'll try using GroovyMock but I won't know right away if it fixes the problem.

Comment: You can take a look at the https://github.com/spockframework/spock/blob/master/spock-core/src/main/java/org/spockframework/mock/runtime/GroovyMockInterceptor.java which maps `getProperty` calls to the correct getter method, i.e. it normalizes the calls to always use the getter on the mock. This is not done by the `JavaMockInterceptor`. So the sentence in the docs above your quote applies `and some of the unique Groovy mock features are needed`, i.e., the handling of the Groovy MOP methods.